# jQuery: Problems with forcing jRumble plugin to stop rumble after delay, fake event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jRumble plugin (http://jackrugile.com/jrumble) to rumble menu items on mouseover. However, the plugin has no setting for rumble time or number of rumbles, so it constantly rumbles until mouseout.

I'v tried like crazy to trigger "stoprumble" 1 second after hover but with no luck :/

This is how my code looks like right now, it works but does continious rumbling until mouseout.

```
$('#menu a img').hover(function(){
    $(this).trigger('startRumble');
    }, function(){
    $(this).trigger('stopRumble');
});
```

I'd need it to work something like this (which dont work):

```
$(this).trigger('startRumble').delay(1000).trigger('stopRumble');
```

Any idea how i can accomplish a single rumble? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.delay()` is different from a `setTimeout()`. `.delay()` just adds an "empty animation" into an objects animation queue. It doesn't block code execution.

to make your rumble rumble only once:

```
$('#menu a img').mouseenter(function(){ 
    var self = $(this);
    self.trigger('startRumble');
    setTimeout(function() { 
        self.trigger('stopRumble'); 
    }, 1000);
});
```

look at demo 19 on http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/

Comment: Thank you very much, this was what i was looking for, weird that i missed it on the demo page :)

Answer (score 0):

On the website the author has a list of examples; example 19 should pretty much do the trick.

```
// This is the 'Demo 19' code, with 'click' replaced with 'hover'.
var demoTimeout;
$('#demo19').hover(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(demoTimeout);
    $this.trigger('startRumble');
    demoTimeout = setTimeout(function(){$this.trigger('stopRumble');}, 1500)
});
```

That should pretty much do what you want, although you might have to experiment a little.

Hope that's helpful!